# Merge multiple raster from subsequent folders

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, qgis-modeler

I have 100 folders and in each folder, I have 50 dem tiffs. I want to merge the tiff from each folder and save it inside the master folder. I tried using Raster as an input in graphical modeler but it doesn't pick all files.

Comment: Test from Processing Tools, GDAL Merge algorithm, this allows you to select folders

Comment: Nope! It does not allow. Tried.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to mosaic the different raster "tiles" into a main thing. You can do this easily with gdal on the shell:

```bsh
for fich in `ls my_folder/*.tif`
do
    cat ${fich} >> file_of_files.txt
done

gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list file_of_files.txt mosaic.vrt
gdal_translate -of GTiff mosaic.vrt, mosaic.tif
```

You can also do something similar using the GDAL Python bindings. In fact the last line just converts the virtual mosaic into a GeoTIFF, but QGIS will read the VRT file reasonably well (it has issues if you change paths, so probably safer to convert to GeoTIFF).

Comment: I want to merge raster from each folder and want to save the merged master inside the same folder, So if I have 100 folders consisting of tiff images, want to save 100 merged tiff inside each folder. Can this be done in Graphical modeler QGIS?